# Is there a universal algorithm for permalinks? (human-readable)

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, permalinks

I'm trying to make a blog script from scratch (PHP) and import posts from Wordpress.
I need to use the exact same permalink algorithm as Wordpress because I want to keep the URLs same. (and just in case I need to go back to Wordpress)

The custom structure is /%postname%/.
I noticed that special characters (such as * - /) and unicode characters are ignored, and if it's a duplicate, a number is automatically added at the end.
Is that all I need to know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wordpress function you need to look at is [`sanitize_title_with_dashes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes) in `wp-includes/formatting.php`.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has defaults, but those defaults may change from version to version. Plus WordPress also lets you customize the permalinks, so I don't think you'll find a "universal" structure.

With that in mind though, here's an article on [URL Design](http://warpspire.com/posts/url-design/) that might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry. My question wasn't very clear. The custom structure is set to /%postname%/. But there are different ways to convert the post title to a url-friendly string.